# Strange margin on the right of my website when loading in mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design

Im just starting to learn responsive design.
When loading this site on say iPhone 5, i get a weird extra margin on the right.
I've went through css inspector and could not find any div that inadvertently create that margin.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8866863/Screen%20Shot%202014-10-08%20at%2012.01.52%20PM.png

Could somebody please help by pinpointing me to the right direction.

thanks a lot!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721966/webkit-margin-adds-unwanted-margin-on-texts

Answer (score 1):

Whenever this has happened to me in the past, I add:

```
* {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

within the browser inspector. This will outline all elements with a 1px solid red border so that the element that is causing the problem can more easily be identified.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot