# Font in the CSS

Tags: html, css

Why is there a gap between red border and B if it is the same font?

[image: Result]

HTML

```
<p>A</p>
<h1>B</h1>
```

CSS

```
body {
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/165v2sd9/2/

Comment: by default p and h1 have different css properties. if you want consistency, you might want to reset all the css properties. check out W3C default css stylesheet http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

Comment: I couldn't find anything wrong with the fiddle. pls check this one.. http://jsfiddle.net/josangel555/5L3oskda/ .. evey element has `32px` height and `20px` gap between.

Comment: I edit the photo. You did not understand me correctly.

Comment: the fiddle you have given doesnt seems to show the exact issue. can u pls  recreate this issue in fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/165v2sd9/2/ - See the gap between red border and B?

Comment: have you checked thee fiddle I posted before, If not pls check... I guess its just an illusion...

Comment: Tip: U can use a chrome extension called `Dimensions` to measure the gaps..

Comment: The gap is so minimal.. just add some padding on the parent element and you'll be g2g

Answer (score 4):

Edit:
I totally misread your question. It looks like that's just how the B is in that font.. You're comparing it to an A. If you compare to a B the gap is there..

Comment: In the given fiddle he is mentioning `em` for `body` tag. In such a case, won't it calculate based on the `font-size` of `body`?

Comment: But why there is that gap?

Comment: @redflar3 yes I believe you're correct in this case. I didn't read the question right, I thought he was talking about vertical gap

Comment: @MarekKobida, yes it's because you're comparing between `A` and `B`, which with the same `size`, the `B` in that font doesn't use all the space (width) given to draw the font, so there's the gap. And the bigger the `size`, the gap will also increase.

Comment: @MarekKobida, here's the difference [http://jsfiddle.net/165v2sd9/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/165v2sd9/4/). You can change the `font-size` of the `span` to a bigger size to see the difference between how the `Arial` `font-family` draw the `A` and `B`. You can change the `font-family` to other type to see how each of them draw it.

Answer (score 0):

The gap is simply there because, `<h1>` and `<p>` are **block** level elements, and therefore a particular `height` has been assigned to them, and a `width` of 100%. If you would like to get ride of the gap, you can try adding `display:inline` on your `<h1>` and `<p>` elements, you can read more about it here:

[Height given to a block element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_heights_and_margins)

Comment: that seems like a poor solution, it doesn't seem like the height should affect the spacing like this. plus what if the intended behavior is to have block elements?

Comment: The height does affect the spacing, you can inspect element and have a look through. If the intended behavior is the to have block elements, you can place your <p> and <h1> tags inside a HTML table

Comment: the spacing on the left and right? I tried playing around with the height and couldn't replicate what you're trying to suggest. but in other words your solution is... go to tables. but i think its a different thing

Comment: try reading about HTML tables, and apply a decent structure, and you will achieve the right functionality, if you're looking forward to see how is it implemented, give me an email and I will send you a sample

Comment: there's reasons to use HTML tables but of making layouts.. should not be the answer. unless you're supporting back to IE 6 or so OR writing html emails. There are now new techniques for handling layout design without having to deal with using tables. the only valid layout reason (other than to present data related information) for html tables is if you really want to get something quick and dirty for vertical alignment but that should be using sparingly and will be hard for future maintenance. tables are for tabular data and should be used minimally elsewhere

Comment: HTML tables currently account for almost all the EDM's being generated and sent through, and thus, I was just providing one example of the usage, elsewhere, you're right, there are much better methods to design and align the main layout. Secondly, the solution provided is ain't quick and dirty, it's In fact the least-code consuming solution provided comparing to yours and the other one. All you've gotta do is to make your block element inline, and make usage of <br/> elements to arrange your paragraphs and headings, without any extra spacing...

Comment: sometimes the least code-consuming is not always the best. because now for every p and every h1, now you have to put another <br> or deal with other layout issues that come with dealing with inline elements. just to deal with a 1-2 px difference of spacing whereas my solution is almost a copy paste and can be generally left alone.

Comment: Well then, in this case, the scale matters, on high scale, my solution is definitely an overkill, whereas yours is much better, and on the contrary just to solve an issue of one div containing several <p> and <h1> tags, my solution is way better than yours.

Comment: but do you really build things that do not scale? Given the context, the OP is looking at p and h1 tags, so your solution would basically be change ALL p and h1 tags to table/inline elements to address this one quibble not just in the context of one div since this will keep occuring because its inbuilt to all p and h1 tags, not just this one specific div

Comment: Yes, I would use this snippet of a code if I'm not having many <p> and <h1> tags, and as OP hasn't stated the scale of the usage, my answer is theoretically correct. And you can specify for it, to only happen in specific div, or on a specific paragraph, therefrom other elements won't be manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the margin at the left you could first initialize your html with the `body` `margin:0;` an then add the margin to the elements.

```
body {
    margin:0;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Arial;
    /*line-height: 2em;*/
}

p,h1 {
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i did an inspection on the elements in the fiddle and I noticed these defaults in the user stylesheet (-margin-before, -margin-after, -margin-start, -margin end)

```
p{
-webkit-margin-before: 3px;
-webkit-margin-after: 3px;
-webkit-margin-start: 3px;
-webkit-margin-end: 3px;
}

h1{
-webkit-margin-before: 0px;
-webkit-margin-after: 0px;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

These seem to control the spacing of the elements, I tried giving it 0px at first but that totally didn't do anything, so i gave the p tag more spacing at the start up to 3px and that seemed to align it... it might be good to bake this into a css restart file... though I have no idea why chrome would want to even have these defaults to begin with ... after looking at another SO question regarding this there's a lot of answers but no clear way to deal with this, but you might want to check the SO for reasons why this would be.... and it seems its not a chrome specific thing...

Here's the SO for reference: 
[-webkit-margin adds unwanted margin on texts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721966/webkit-margin-adds-unwanted-margin-on-texts)