# Extra space below <div> element

Tags: html, css, margin

There is some extra space after div with id "header" element (second div). If I remove p, no space between div element. how to kill space between two div element without removing p element and why it act like it?

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div#page {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

div#header {
  width: 960px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

div#main {
  height: 400px;
  width: 960px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="header">header</div>
  <div id="main">
    <p>we make your business</p>
    <p>Con panna organic americano grinder single origin white mug chicory arabica breve cortado. In sit, aromatic lungo shop body redeye.</p>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <button>about us</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to clarify which `div` element

Comment: Give the div which writes "we make your business", `margin-top: 0`

Comment: Try using a css reset.

Comment: `div#header {
    width: 960px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-bottom: -16px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason it happens is `p` tags have an auto margin. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721966/webkit-margin-adds-unwanted-margin-on-texts)

Comment: @rajini-raja it's not fully correct, the most browsers add margins by default, not only Webkit-browsers. And it's not a problem in your case, the problem is [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing). Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42412009/2570353).

Answer (score 2):

It's because of [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing):

> **Parent and first/last child**
>   If there is no border, padding, inline content, [block_formatting_context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) created or [*clearance*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) to separate the [margin-top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-top) of a block from the [margin-top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-top) of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height), [min-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height), or [max-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height) to separate the [margin-bottom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-bottom) of a block from the [margin-bottom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-bottom) of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

You could remove `margin-top` from your first `<p>` element, and add `padding-top` instead to `div#main`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div#page {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

div#header {
  width: 960px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

div#main {
  height: 400px;
  width: 960px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

div#main p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="header">header</div>
  <div id="main">
    <p>we make your business</p>
    <p>Con panna organic americano grinder single origin white mug chicory arabica breve cortado. In sit, aromatic lungo shop body redeye.</p>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <button>about us</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove space between these two div then add this CSS:-

```
#main p:first-child {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just using * in stead of body element

```css
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
div#page{
    width:960px;
    margin:10px auto;
}
div#header{
    width:960px;
    height:80px;
    background-color:lightgray;
}
div#main{
    height:400px;
    width:960px;
    background-color:antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
        <div id="header">
           header
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <p>we make your business</p>
            <p>Con panna organic americano grinder single origin white mug chicory arabica breve cortado. In sit, aromatic lungo shop body redeye.</p>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <button>
                    about us
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
div#page{
    width:960px;
    margin:10px auto;
}
div#header{
    width:960px;
    height:80px;
    background-color:lightgray;
}
div#main{
    height:400px;
    width:960px;
    background-color:antiquewhite;
}
p.demo{
 margin:0px;
}



<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <div id="page">
      <div id="header">
        header
      </div>
      <div id="main">
       <p class="demo">we make your business</p>
       <p>Con panna organic americano grinder single origin white mug chicory arabica breve cortado. In sit, aromatic lungo shop body redeye.</p>
      <form action="" method="post">
          <button>about us
                    </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

quick solution

> add `padding-top:1px;` to **div#main**

smart solution

> use **flex**, benefits: responsive, less code, more readable, modern

```css
/* the main content will take all remaining space, makin it responsive */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div#page {
  /* make page fill all available space*/
  height: 100%;
  /* change predefined value to 100%, and adjust spaces */
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  /* flex usage itself */
  display: flex;
  /* place divs horizontally */
  flex-direction: column;
}

div#header {
  height: 80px;
  /* header will not resize when window resized*/
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

div#main {
  /* responsive container, remove width/height, any predefined values */
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="header">
    header
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <p>we make your business</p>
    <p>Con panna organic americano grinder single origin white mug chicory arabica breve cortado. In sit, aromatic lungo shop body redeye.</p>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <button>about us</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flex for this case? I don't think so. You should use flex only when you need its capabilities, not for every case instead of block-level elements.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov disagree, i myself use flex all the time, it has super useful powers, why bother about blocks hmm? Flex will solve small OP problem with that `p`, but also will help to prevent future refactorings, its like killin 2 rabbits with bazuka, kinda _Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime_, cuz im cool dude haha :p anyway have a funny day todays' my birthday <3